# Why does Feature Importance change with each iteration of a Decision Tree Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, decision-trees

After applying PCA to reduce the number of features, I am using a DecisionTreeClassifier for a ML problem

[image]
Additionally I want to compute the feature_importances_. However, with each iteration of the DecisionTreeClassifier, the feature_importances_ change.

Iteration #1

[image]

Iteration #2

[image]

Why would it change? I thought the initial split was made on a feature to "produce the purest subsets (weighted by their size)". Acting on the same training set, why would that change?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` help](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn-tree-decisiontreeclassifier):

> The features are always randomly permuted at each split. Therefore, the best found split may vary, even with the same training data and max_features=n_features, if the improvement of the criterion is identical for several splits enumerated during the search of the best split. To obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting, random_state has to be fixed.

Also, you might want to have a look at my [critique on feature importance](https://martin-thoma.com/feature-importance/).

Comment: Ah, in the future I need to read to the very end of the documentation ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: Even if you keep random_state, the features are getting changed for every iterations.